# Redraw window return immediately without painting whole window in Excel.exe process in win32

Tags: excel, redraw

I have excel.exe process now from that process i got the hWnd of that opened excel.exe.
Now I want to redraw that opened excel worksheet. So i use this code to force redraw whole window , So I can capture whole text using its ExtextOutW Methods.

```
 //Get Rectangle of the Window
RECT UpdateRect;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &UpdateRect);
```

//Active Window and make them fore ground

```
SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SetFocus(hWnd);

// Call redraw Window
RedrawWindow(hWnd, &UpdateRect, NULL,  RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

When My this method call first time I will get all the text of that excel.exe. Then Second time call it will return only the focused text ( One text). then sub sequence call will always return focus text.

**Why every time it is not returning all the cell text of the excel ?**